# Use of the standby attribute of the object element

Tags: html, object, standby

I was just going over the OBJECT element in HTML (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.3) .  I've done a few flash projects and a few silverlight, and so would have seen the element in passing.
For some of the flash, I would have written some 'loading' logic to let the user know the actual flash body is loading.
What is the level of support for this standby attribute in browsers? Have you used it before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/object/standby), "Poor support is provided for this attribute. It’s probably better to use a JavaScript technique to create a custom content-is-loading message in the style of your web page or site, which can subsequently be replaced or removed once the object’s content has loaded."